# How to share heap allocated vector of boxed trait type across threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

So my current use case is I need to:

1. Create a `Vec<Box<Material>>` where Material is a trait.
2. Push boxed structs that impl Material into this Vec.
3. Share a read only version of this vec to multiple threads.

My current approach is to use an Arc pointer for the Vec<..> and then clone it for each thread.

for example:

```rust
let mut materials: Vec<Box<Material>> = Vec::new();
// ... push stuff into materials
let materials = Arc::new(materials);
let mat_cloned = materials.clone();
// pool is a threadpool
pool.execute(move|| {
    // do read stuff with mat_cloned.
}
```

However I get the compiler error: `dyn 'materials::Material' cannot be shared between threads safely`

My understanding of it is that:

1. Materials is a heap allocated vector of boxed pointers to various Material implementations.
2. I then wrap with with an Arc type which is an atomically reference counted read-only pointer.
3. I should be able to share this pointer with threads safely?

material::Material can't be shared safely but why not a Arc pointer to it?

Answer (score 1):

If your Material trait is defined like:

```rust
trait Material{
...
}
```

Then, define it like:

```rust
trait Material: Send + Sync{
...
}
```

Here `trait Material: Send + Sync` means that every type that implements Material must also implement Send and Sync

> material::Material can't be shared safely but why not a Arc pointer to it?

You have to let the compiler know that Box happens to hold something with the trait that happens to fulfill `Send` and `Sync`

## OR

You can just change the declaration of `materials` to (For the same reason as above):

```rust
let mut materials: Vec<Box<Material + Send + Sync>> = Vec::new();
```